# How to process this function-based-view using class-based views?

Tags: ajax, django

I'm following this tutorial [about ajax and crud](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/11/15/how-to-implement-a-crud-using-ajax-and-json.html). The tutorial uses function-based-views approach, instead, I want to use class-based-views, particularly for this view.

```
def book_create(request):
    data = dict()

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = BookForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            data['form_is_valid'] = True
            books = Book.objects.all()
            data['html_book_list'] = render_to_string('books/includes/partial_book_list.html', {
                'books': books
            })
        else:
            data['form_is_valid'] = False
    else:
        form = BookForm()

    context = {'form': form}
    data['html_form'] = render_to_string('books/includes/partial_book_create.html',
        context,
        request=request
    )
    return JsonResponse(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the example of the class based view based on your case.

```
from django.views import View

class BookCreateView(View):

    def post(self, request):
        form = BookForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            data['form_is_valid'] = True
            books = Book.objects.all()
            data['html_book_list'] = render_to_string('books/includes/partial_book_list.html', {
                'books': books
            })
        else:
            data['form_is_valid'] = False
        context = {'form': form}
        data['html_form'] = render_to_string('books/includes/partial_book_create.html',
            context,
            request=request
        )
        return JsonResponse(data)

    def get(self, request):
        data = dict()
        form = BookForm()
        context = {'form': form}
        data['html_form'] = render_to_string('books/includes/partial_book_create.html',
            context,
            request=request
        )
        return JsonResponse(data)
```